# Url rewriting not properly applied

Tags: c#, asp.net, url-rewriting

I have a web portal on which I have applied Url rewritting using rewriteModule.dll.
I have define a rule like

```
<rule source="Voices" destination="Others/MyVoices.aspx"/>
```

It runs successfully.

But In my admin login I have a page named DefineVoices.aspx [In admin login I have not applied rewritting], when i have called DefineVoices.aspx then Url is converted into 
/Admin/DefineOthers/MyVoices.aspx.aspx

Please give me a solution without chage in  my current url rule...

Comment: @ic. I cannt understand your revision please explain it.. thanxxx.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to change your url replace algorithm because you might be using direct string replace. Which causing the url

/Admin/DefineVoices.aspx

to

/Admin/DefineOthers/MyVoices.aspx.aspx

In your rule you have specified  a rule that replaces the word Voices to Others/MyVoices.aspx.

I would recommend to update your replace alogirthm and use Regular expression properly and *only* replace part of url not words.

e.g. exact word /voices to /Others/MyVoices.aspx

Comment: Sir please you provide me Regular expression for this purpose... thanxx a lot